# Merge Join [1311]: The comparison flags for the columns with SortKeyPosition value 1 do not match.

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I have a

Source #1: OLE DB Source

```
SELECT        *
FROM            ABCDB.dbo.XYZ
WHERE        (CRMTransOpport = 0)
ORDER BY EmailAddress

And Source Output  “IsSort = True”
And Source output Column EmailAddress  output sort =1
```

Source #2:  From Microsoft CRM

```
fetch mapping='logical'>
     <entity name='contact'>
         <attribute name='emailaddress1'/>
         <attribute name='contactid'/>
             <order attribute="emailaddress1" />
     </entity> </fetch>
```

The objective to into a Merge Join and ultimately into Microsoft CRM without email duplication.

So both are sorting and merge with just those setting…

However, to go into Microsoft CRM I need:
Source #1:

```
Source output Column: 
     emailaddress to have the comparison flag set to “ignore case”
```

So that capitalization of the email address is ignore – without this Merges that should happen are not happening:
    ie  myname@abd.com  is not matching with MyName@abC.com

When I add this setting I get the following error:

```
Error   1   Validation error. Merge Join [1311]: The comparison flags for the columns with SortKeyPosition value 1 do not match.
```

I am on SQL 2014 Server  SSIS.
Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this? DO I need to do 2 different steps or am I missing something in this set up?

Answer (score 0):

I was provide the answer and wanted to share it in case it could assist someone else.

Here is what they said:

You need to ensure the "ignore case" flag is set on both sides of the “>”inputs. This can be done in the "Advanced Editor"

Just be sure both sides are actually sorting while ignoring case (you can't “>”just tell it, you actually have to do it)

RyanAB

[My Post of the question with Ryan's answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76647572-d28b-448b-87cc-00f101869d7e/merge-join-1311-the-comparison-flags-for-the-columns-with-sortkeyposition-value-1-do-not-match?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

**Bottom line I did not have the "ignorecase" on BOTH sources.**

So with this information here is how I was able to solve the problem.

```
On Source #2
 ... advanced editing
 ...... Output Column - Selected  "emailaddress" 
 .......... Selected  "ignore case"
```

Merge Join error went away.

And the ALL records successfully transferred from SQL to a CRM Opportunity finding the appropriate CRM Contact by ignoring case sensitivity.